# Capybara Webkit Failed to build gem native extension. OSX

Tags: macos, qt, homebrew, zsh, capybara-webkit

The capybara-webkit gem fails to build its native extensions on my machine

OSX Yosemite 10.10.1

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Xarch_x86_64'
make[1]: *** [build/webkit_server.gch/c++] Error 1
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_default-ordered] Error 2
Command 'make' failed

$ which qmake
 /usr/local/bin/qmake

$ qmake -v
QMake version 2.01a
 Using Qt version 4.8.6 in /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/lib



 $ brew -v
 Homebrew 0.9.5


 $ ruby -v
 ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
```

zshell path:

```
 export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
```

Is there any other information that would be helpful to diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by upgrading gcc

```
brew upgrade gcc
```

Comment: While upgrading it says, `Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/gcc`